# Lists inside dictionaries in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm currently trying to insert a dictionary which contains a list into my MongoDB database in this format:

```
guildId: myDiscordGuildId,
 questions: [
   'Do you like waffles?',
   'Who put the bop in the bop shoo bop shoo bop?'
 ]
```

However, this is a Javascript collection. However, im using python and I am unsure about how to do this.

I know how to put a list inside of a dictionary as seen here:

```
mydict = {'fruits': ['banana', 'apple', 'orange'],
         'vegetables': ['pepper', 'carrot'], 
         'cheese': ['swiss', 'cheddar', 'brie']}
```

But, if my list is a variable defined like this:

my_list = []

How can i use this list variable inside of a dictionary to get the same result as the fruit dictionary above?

This list is manipulated through my discord bot and is changed.

I know how to use lists inside of dictionaries when the values are hard coded. But when using variables I am unsure.

Comment: The question is not clear. Please clarify what is the input, what is the expected output.

Comment: You can just put the variable name where you normally hardcode your list.

`mydict = {'fruits': my_fruit,'vegetables': my_vegetables, 'cheese': my_cheese}`

Comment: Also, if this question is about MongoDB, make sure to tag that c:

Comment: Thanks, I have since fixed it. 
Sorry for the bad explanation

                new_application = {
                    "guildId": ctx.author.id,
                    "questions": questions
                }

Answer (score 0):

```
                new_application = {
                    "guildId": ctx.author.id,
                    "questions": questions
                }
```

Fixed

Answer (score 0):

If i understood question correctly, you can add keys and values in initialization like this:

```
myDict = {'a' : my_list}
```

or after initialization:

```
myDict['b'] = [1,2,3]
```

or

```
 myDict['c'] = my_list
```